# Foreach in my own template system

Tags: php

I'm trying to make my own template system, but I'm stuck at this point. I don't know how to do it.

In my template file I currently have:

```
@list $users => $user:
    <li>{{$user}}</li>
@endlist
```

I want it to work as a foreach that displays the users in my $this->users variable.

I have tried this, but I'm stuck here. I hope someone can help me :-)

My code so far(which doesn't work):

```
preg_match_all("/\@list(.*)\=\>(.*)\:/is", $e, $hmm);

  foreach ( $hmm as $hm):
     print_r($hm);exit;
     $eval = 'foreach ('.$hm[1].' as '.$hm[2].'):';

     eval($eval);
     echo ":P";

  endforeach;
```

Comment: I don't mean to sound uncreative but have you looked at all the existing templating engines?  Parts of your syntax resembles Twig

Comment: Why you don't just replace your code @list ... by php. I mean you have to replace this code when it match your regex by a php foreach (twig works like that)

Comment: Because i will make my own template.

Comment: Most PHP templating engines compile template files to PHP for faster execution and resuse.  They don't use Eval

Comment: Using `eval` for this is just `eval`.

Comment: Writing template engines in language that basically was meant as template engine is IMO pretty crazy ;) (and adds a lot of overhead mostly giving not much more than other syntax...)

Comment: Listing, i am trying to make my OWN template, i know the other template engine, but that is not my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to scare you, but have a look at the Twig_Lexer:

https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Lexer.php
It is a token parser which turns the Twig syntax into its own language.

However, regarding your immediate requirements, this is the `For` node it uses to compile a `foreach loop`:

https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Node/For.php

Even if you don't copy it exactly, and even if you do use `eval`, it should give you some good clues on how to do it, for example the use of a `$context` array to store Twig variables.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this code can be of some guidance : [Old template class](http://pastebin.com/tdXAPfYx)

Template :

```
   $template = '{Template.Repeat.Users}
        <li>{Template.Var.userName}</li>
    {/Template.Repeat}';
```

PHP :

```
echo TemplateMananger::parse($template, array(array('userName'= > 'foo'), array('userName' => 'bar'));
```

Anyway with template engines like Twig out there its not advisable to do it yourself.
But perphaps my class can give u some insights to create your own

Good luck